# Problem with model.addAtribute (spring, mvc)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, post, model-view-controller

I have object in object (obj Product(id, name price) in obj CartItem (qunatity, obj Product)), how should I add atributes to jsp? Right now i have something like this, and TomCat give me exection [org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing]

```
@PostMapping(path = "/showCart", produces = "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
    public String showCart(Model model) {
        List<CartItem> cartItems = cart.getCartItems();
        
        model.addAttribute("cartItems", cartItems);
        return "showCart";
    }
```

**JSP:**

```
 <c:forEach items="${cartItems}" var="cartItem">
            <tr>
                <td>${cartItem.getProduct.id}</td>
                <td>${cartItem.getProduct.name}</td>
                <td>${cartItem.getProduct.price}</td>
                <td>${cartItem.quantity}</td>
                <button name="remove" type="submit" value="${cartItem.getProduct.id}">REMOVE</button>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Code is not finished, but i first i need to fix this problem. I will be grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Use field names (ex. `cartItem.product.id`) instead of getter name